# Writing to a delta table with Spark in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am new to Apache Spark and am trying to write some rows into a Delta Table (locally currently, eventually into ADLSgen2) using the [dotnet\spark](https://github.com/dotnet/spark) package. I'm using the following approach, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398552/create-dataframe-from-c-sharp-list-spark-for-net), notably the `.Format("delta")` call:

```
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql.Types;

public static async Task WriteToDelta() 
    {
    
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.Builder().AppName("DeltaTableWrite").GetOrCreate();
        // Create a schema for the data
        StructType schema = new StructType(new[]
        {
        new StructField("id", new IntegerType()),
        new StructField("name", new StringType()),
        new StructField("age", new IntegerType())
        });

        // Create a DataFrame with sample data
        DataFrame df = spark.CreateDataFrame(new[]
        {
            new GenericRow(new object[]
            {1, "John Smith", 40}),
            new GenericRow(new object[]
            {2, "Jane Doe", 20}),
            new GenericRow(new object[]
            {3, "Bob Smith", 30})
        }, schema);

        // Write the DataFrame as a Delta table to blob storage
       df.Write()
        .Format("delta")
        .Option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .Mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .Save(@"C:\source\path\to\table");
    }
```

However, when I run this I get the `Failed to find data source: delta. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html` error, which I understand to mean that I have to install the [delta-sharing package](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-sharing). In their README though, there is no mention of support for C#/.NET, and I'm not sure how to install/add the package as part of the Apache Spark Connector. Is this something I'm installing for Java using Maven? Can someone highlight how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Delta Lake libraries as described in the [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#set-up-apache-spark-with-delta-lake). You have two choices:

- if you're using `spark-submit` to run the app, then you need to add following to command-line:

```
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0 \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

- Specify the same options but when setting the session:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.Builder().AppName("DeltaTableWrite")
   .Config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
   .Config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
   .Config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0")
   .GetOrCreate();
```

P.S. Make sure that Delta Lake version matches the Spark version as per [doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html).